# How to translate a Optional mapping to Stream mapping in Java

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I have this current logic:

```
    List<String> priceUnitCodes = ofNullable(product.getProductPrices())
            .map(ProductPrices::getProductPrices)
            .flatMap(productPrices -> productPrices.stream()) // << error highlight
            .map(ProductPrice::getPriceBase)
            .map(PriceBase::getPriceUnit)
            .map(UniversalType::getCode)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where in IntelliJ the `flatMap` part is highlighted and shows the following error hint:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that Stream<ProductPrice> conforms to  Optional<? extends U>
```

I know that `Optionals` and `Stream` are two different things but I wonder if there is a way to combine them so I can follow up an `Optional<List<?>>` with a `Stream` afterwards.

Comment: What is `ofNullable`? We can't see you imports, so is that [`Optional.ofNullable(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable(T)) or [`Stream.ofNullable(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T))? --- What is return type of `ProductPrices::getProductPrices`?

Comment: its `Optional.ofNullable`

Comment: You have a class `ProductPrices` which has a method `getProductPrices`, so to get the product prices, you have to call `product.getProductPrices().getProductPrices()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Java 9+, you can use `Optional.stream`, followed by `flatMap`:

```
ofNullable(product.getProductPrices())
.map(ProductPrices::getProductPrices)
.stream()
.flatMap(Collection::stream) //assuming getProductPrices returns a Collection
...
```

`Optional.stream` returns an empty stream if the optional is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are starting with an `Optional`, you have to decide what to return when that `Optional` is empty.

One way is to put the `Stream` pipeline inside the `Optional`'s `map`:

```
List<String> priceUnitCodes = ofNullable(product.getProductPrices())
        .map(ProductPrices::getProductPrices)
        .map(productPrices -> productPrices.stream()
                                           .map(ProductPrice::getPriceBase)
                                           .map(PriceBase::getPriceUnit)
                                           .map(UniversalType::getCode)
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .orElse(null);
```

Or course, if the `map` operations inside the `Stream` pipeline may return `null`, additional changes will be required (to avoid `NullPointerException`).

On the other hand, if they can never return `null`, they can be chained into a single `map`:

```
List<String> priceUnitCodes = ofNullable(product.getProductPrices())
        .map(ProductPrices::getProductPrices)
        .map(productPrices -> productPrices.stream()
                                           .map(pp -> pp.getPriceBase().getPriceUnit().getCode())
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: I don't get the explanation behind the single `map` vs multiple chained. Not really clear if you're trying to say an NPE handling is a must for such cases or not.

Comment: @Naman I'm saying that if null values may be returned by any of the methods called within the Stream pipeline, my code (both snippets) is insufficient (you'd have to either filter out null values, or wrap the element of the Stream will an Optional). If null values are not possible, both snippets are correct, but I prefer the single `map` version.

Comment: Okay, to me the sentence "*On the other hand, if they can never return null, they can be chained into a single map*", sounded like if they can never return null then can be chained into a single map. What I believe on the other hand is they can anyway be chained into a single `map` based on the readability perception of the consumer towards method references Vs lambda representation. Functionally they would boh throw `NullPointerException` for failure cases.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution would be to get the value of the `Optional` using `orElse` and this can be done without upgrading to Java-9. It would look like:

```
List<String> priceUnitCodes = Optional.ofNullable(product.getProductPrices())
            .map(ProductPrices::getProductPrices)
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList()) // get the value from Optional
            .stream()
            .map(ProductPrice::getPriceBase)
            .map(PriceBase::getPriceUnit)
            .map(UniversalType::getCode)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```